# Call parent class modifier possible?

Tags: solidity, inheritance, modifiers

I want to do the following:

```
contract Base {
    bool public active;

    modifier canSetMetadata() {
        require(active == false);
        _;
    }
}

contract BaseWithMetadataControl is Base {
    address public metadataControl;

    modifier canSetMetadata() {
        if(msg.sender != metadataControl) {
            super.canSetMetadata();
        }
        _;
    }
}
```

So the child class should call the parent's class modifier. It doesn't seem to be possible but I don't want to duplicate the modifier code because it's likely to change...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could override an internal function that implements the check

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Base {
    bool public active;

    modifier canSetMetadata() {
        require(canSetMetadata_());
        _;
    }

    function canSetMetadata_() internal view returns (bool) {
        return (active == false);
    }
}

contract BaseWithMetadataControl is Base {
    address public metadataControl;

    function canSetMetadata_() internal view returns (bool) {
        if(msg.sender != metadataControl) {
            return super.canSetMetadata_();
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I also came up with meanwhile :)